# Run a batch file continuously after 20 minutes (windows xp OS)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to run a batch file which contain command
arp -d * ( used to flush the MAC entry table)

I want to execute this batch file continuously after 20-20 minutes .. regulary ?
How can i do this with batch programming ?

Plz guide me ..

hoping for quick and positive response ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont have the sleep command on your system you can get it from the Windows Resource Kit.

```
:BEGIN
ARP -d *
SLEEP 1200 
GOTO BEGIN
```

Comment: yeah .. i got it frm above link.. i downloaded sleep.exe and put it in c:windows:system32

Answer (score 3):

With the following links you'll be able to achieve what you want:

[How to execute commands in a batch file in timed intervals.](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000036.htm)

[Run a program every 30 seconds](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/run-a-program-every-30-seconds/18105.html)

[run batch file every 30 seconds](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/2000/Q_21244443.html)